# Autowire failed in cucumber Step Def test

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a series cucumber feature files and a list of associated step def tests in current project

in the step def tests package, I have this Hook definition

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class Hooks {
    ....
}
```

and RunCukesTest

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features", glue = { "com.myapp.test.jersey.rest.v1" })
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class RunCukesTest {
    ....
}
```

above classpaths are correct.
And there is one of the step def test

```
package com.myapp.test.jersey.rest.v1;

....
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class OrderCreateServiceTest {
    ....
    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository repository;
}
```

However I got follow error by Spring Boot

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Then if I take out the `@ContextConfiguration` from step def class, like this

```
//@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class CashpointCreateServiceTest {
```

apparently autowire of repository object will fail by throwing `NullPointerException`

It's greatly appreciated if anyone can share 
(1) With `Hook` and `CukeTest` configuration, how to autowire bean in the step def class?
(2) Is it ok to have `@ContextConfiguration` in both `Hook` and `CukeTest` class?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the ContextConfiguration on RunCukesTest class. For running cucumber tests I use the following setup.

Junit test class to launch the cucumber tests:

```
package mypackage.test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test-integration/resources/features")
public class RunFeatures {

}
```

Base class which all step definition classes extend. This is so that all the step classes have the same spring annotations.

```
package mypackage.test.steps;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

import mypackage.Application;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Application.class })
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class BaseSteps {

}
```

Then the tests steps

```
package mypackage.test.steps;

import mypackage.repo.SampleRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class SampleSteps extends BaseSteps {

    @Autowired
    private SampleRepo sampleRepo;

    @When("^Sample repo is called$")
    public void no_words_are_saved() {
         sampleRepo.findAll("something");
    }
```

I don't understand what your Hooks class is for. I've only used annotated hooks in cucumber-jvm (e.g. @Before or @After). If you need some other hook, can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do?