# How to @Autowire a REST service class (Spring boot) in a Cucumber step implementation?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, cucumber, autowired

Like the title says, I want to test a Scenario in Cucumber where I add a new DTO to the database using a method of my service class. The issue is that I can't use @Autowire, and don't know how to enable it. I've attempted several solutions for similar questions [(Like this one)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53518163/12563878), but I don't know where I'm going wrong. For reference, I'm doing this in Intellij and and this is what my structure looks like:

[image: Project Structure]

This is my Cucumber start class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/unit/resources/features")
public class RunCucumberUnitTest {

}
```

And this is the BaseStep class that all steps are going to inherit:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BasicLoginTestApplication.class},
                      initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class BaseStep {
}
```

In my step implementation, I attempt this:

```
public class UserServiceTestStepImplementation extends BaseStep{

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
```

But I still get a null pointer exception for the userService. I'd really like some ideas on what I could do.

EDIT: I tried to add a dummy method to the BaseStep class to make Cucumber recognize it as glue. I think that happened, but then I got an exception saying I can't extend step implementation classes or hooks. I removed the extend from the StepImplementation class and just put the annotations there. Still get null pointer exception. This is the step impl. now:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BasicLoginTestApplication.class},
    initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment =   SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class UserServiceTestStepImplementation /*extends BaseStep*/{

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Before
    public void springContext() {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to add to your BaseStep class this code

```
@Before
public void setup_cucumber_spring_context(){
    // Dummy method so cucumber will recognize this class as glue
    // and use its context configuration.
}
```

Comment: I think this did make it recognizable, but the annotations I used didn't solve the problem (added EDIT) to post

Comment: The dummy method should be located within @SpringBootTest annotation
Please check the example 
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/spring-txn/src/test/java/io/cucumber/examples/spring/txn

Comment: As you can see in my post, the dummy method is within the class with the @SpringBootTest annotation. It still didn't work. Thank you so much for the example link though, I'll try to make it work that way.

Comment: I tried setting the Spring Context that way, but it still didn't work. The @Autowired still doesn't work and leaves the userService null.

Comment: Just checking: Do you have cucumber-spring in your dependencies?

Comment: Here is one more based on your classes https://github.com/cdene/cucumber_example